Sending Emails via Gmail SMTP with OAuth2.0 in ASP.NET Core 2.1 (Backend-Only)
I'm encountering a roadblock in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 backend application. Up until now, I've been sending emails using the Gmail SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com) with basic authentication (username and password). However, Google has rightly deprecated this method for less secure apps, mandating OAuth2.0 for improved security.
While I grasp the importance of OAuth2.0, I need some guidance on implementing it effectively in a backend-only application that lacks a user interface for login. Any insights or pointers to relevant resources would be highly appreciated!
PS : I know about app-passwords but they are less secure too so Want to go with this OAuth2.0 approach.

To send emails using OAuth 2.0 in .NET, please refer to the Google OAuth 2.0 API Client Library documentation for .Net or Gmail OAuth guide on the EmailArchitect website.
